# Check if div contain equal text to aria-label value in another div

Tags: jquery

I have html like this:

```
<h1 class="title">Floor 3</h1>

<div class="floor" aria-label="Floor 1>Bla bla</div>
<div class="floor" aria-label="Floor 2>Bla bla</div>
<div class="floor" aria-label="Floor 3>Bla bla</div>
```

How to check if h1 text is equal to .floor aria-label value? And if so add class ".highlight" to .floor div?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you can use `filter()` to find the relevant `.floor` element from the matching text in the `h1` element.

```js
$('.floor')
  .filter((i, el) => $(el).attr('aria-label') === $('h1').text())
  .addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title">Floor 3</h1>

<div class="floor" aria-label="Floor 1">Bla bla</div>
<div class="floor" aria-label="Floor 2">Bla bla</div>
<div class="floor" aria-label="Floor 3">Bla bla</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.floor').each(function (i, obj) {
   if ($(obj).attr('aria-label') == $('h1.title').text()) {                    
      $(obj).addClass('highlight');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to refer to the attribute by specifying a variable for the text of the `h1` tag.

```js
let text = $('.title').text().trim();
$(".floor[aria-label='" + text + "']").addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="title">Floor 3</h1>
  <div class="floor" aria-label="Floor 1">Bla bla</div>
  <div class="floor" aria-label="Floor 2">Bla bla</div>
  <div class="floor" aria-label="Floor 3">Bla bla</div>
```